# C++20 modified definition of aggregate, how to initialize instances with constant array of bytes?

Tags: c++, c++20, aggregate-initialization

I understand that C++20 has modified the definition of aggregate.

In the following code, we have a `Packet` class with just a fixed-size array of bytes (more than 4 in the real code). It must match the binary representation, including for arrays and vectors of `Packet`. So, we cannot define some higher level of abstraction, just keep the low-level representation. And, because we manipulate constant packets, it must be initialized using some constant list of byte literals.

```
#include <cstdint>

class Packet
{
public:
    uint8_t b[4];
    Packet() = default;
    Packet(const Packet& p) = default;
};

Packet p {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

Up to C++17, the class is an aggregate and can be initialized as in instance "p" or using "p = {{...".

With C++20, this is no longer possible because of the default constructors (we need at least the copy constructor).

See the various compiler errors:

```
==== gcc -std=c++17

==== clang -std=c++17

==== gcc -std=c++20
init.cpp:18:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘Packet::Packet(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   18 | Packet p {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
      |                       ^
init.cpp:13:5: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Packet::Packet(const Packet&)’
   13 |     Packet(const Packet& p) = default;
      |     ^~~~~~
init.cpp:13:26: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const Packet&’
   13 |     Packet(const Packet& p) = default;
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
init.cpp:12:5: note: candidate: ‘constexpr Packet::Packet()’
   12 |     Packet() = default;
      |     ^~~~~~
init.cpp:12:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

==== clang -std=c++20
init.cpp:18:8: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Packet'
Packet p {{1, 2, 3, 4}};
       ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
init.cpp:13:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const Packet'
    Packet(const Packet& p) = default;
    ^
init.cpp:12:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 0 arguments, but 1 was provided
    Packet() = default;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I have tried various ways to declare an additional constructor using a `std::initializer_list<uint8_t>` parameter without finding the right way to initialize the field "b" from this parameter.

I have seen similar reports on SO and other sites without a working solution in the case of an array field.

Ideally, I would like to find an initialization syntax which works for all levels of standards. If a specific constructor needs to be #ifdef'ed on C++20, this is acceptable. However, there are too many initializations of Packet instances to have distinct syntaxes from C++11 to C++20 (pre-C++11 is not supported by the application).

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW what you have here is essentially `std::array`.  `std::array` is an aggregate so it must be laid just like you want.

Answer (score 4):

Don't explicitly `default` things you don't have to. There is no reason to `default` *either* of those constructors; you'll get them either way.

It is the presence of an explicitly `default`ed constructor that stops it from being an aggregate. Remove those, and your code works just fine on all C++ versions post-11.

Comment: Thanks, but nope. The copy constructor is required, in default form at least. In the real application, I also declare an assignment operator for Packet and I also use instructions such as "return p:" where "P" is a Packet. Without the copy constructor, gcc complains "error: implicitly-declared ‘constexpr ts::TSPacket::TSPacket(const ts::TSPacket&)’ is deprecated because ‘ts::TSPacket’ has user-provided ‘ts::TSPacket& ts::TSPacket::operator=(const ts::TSPacket&)".

Comment: @ThierryLelegard You shouldn't need to create your own `operator =`.  As long as all the members of your class have an `operator =` then the compiler will generate one for you.

Comment: @ThierryLelegard: "*I also declare an assignment operator for Packet*" Then stop doing that. What is this copy assignment operator doing that a copy constructor would not also have to do? What circumstances would lead you to have a user-provided copy assignment operator but not a user-provided copy constructor?

Comment: I've run into exactly this problem with aggregates containing const members. One has to write an assignment. Still an aggregate but the default copy ctor is  deprecated. Annoying. No way to fix w/o losing the aggregate trait.

Comment: @doug: Deleted, not "deprecated". And it's ultimately based on what it means for a type to be an aggregate. A conceptual aggregate is one where any combination of values is meaningful, where any object can assume any combination of values at any time. If a member is `const`, that's no longer true.

Comment: @NicolBolas No, the default copy ctor is not deleted when writing a copy assignment. But c++20 does deprecate it. The move copy/assignments are deleted. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/depr.impldec

Answer (score -1):

In case your actual implementation is not defaulting your constructors and you can't use Nicol's answer, you can create an array constructor like this to keep the rest of the code identical:

```
Packet(const decltype(b)& a)
{
    memcpy(b, a, sizeof a);
}
```

[Working Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98d48ee03eea46c4)

Comment: Your example link isn't working

Comment: Yeah noticed that. For some reason the online ide I used doesnt update the link. So I just removed it

Comment: You can use [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) or [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) for sharing live code examples.  Compiler explorer gives you a lot more information as well, like the generated assembly code.

Comment: Thanks added a new link